# Прокрутка элемента на JS или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Скажите, есть ли решение моему вопросу?
Имеется:

```
<div>в котором очень много контента</div>
```

У него соответственно своя прокрутка.
Периодически весь контент этого div обновляется с помощью AJAX.
Проблема кроется в том, что после обновления контента в элементе - прокрутка скидывается на начало.
Если мы читали что то в конце прокрутки, то всё скидывается на начало.
Как этого избежать? Перед AJAX замерять как-то на сколько прокручен div? А после ajax как-то устанавливать длину прокрутки? Но как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой пример. Прокрутите скролл на любую позицию, и он будет оставаться там, несмотря на добавление текста:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
let scrollTopRemember = 0;

setInterval(()=>{
  
  // Запоминаем позицию скролла
  scrollTopRemember = div.scrollTop;
  
  // Добавляем текст
  div.innerHTML += `Немного текста добавлено, ${Date.now()}<br>`;
  
  // Восстанавливаем позицию скролла
  div.scrollTop = scrollTopRemember;
  
}, 1000 );
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```